# Display current year on 2013 list

Tags: list, date-time

How do I display the current year on list date?

Example picture below, only the items modified last year or before have the year displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Date is by default shown in **Friendly** format. One quick workaround you can do is to go to **List Settings**--> Click on **Modified** --> Change **Display Format** to **Standard** . Then dates will be displayed as mm/dd/yyyy format:

[image]

Comment: Hmm..some of my dates have switched to Friendly when we went to 2013 and some haven't. Bizarre! Love easy fixes, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, just extra info when working with past dates

```
 =TEXT([Modified],"YYY")
```

In an extra Calculated Column **Year** gets you the Year only,
You can then use that in View Filters, Sorts or Group By settings

A list year filter setting would then be:

[image]

I tried to use functions in here, but couldn't get it to work

You can't use

```
 =YEAR( [Modified] )
```

for your formula, because it will be formatted as number with *thousands* separator.

Answer (score 1):

If its a list view, you can format date column with the help of JSLink. JSLink will help you to conditional format the date.

If its a Display form you can use JSLink or jquery to conditional format the date.